# Can I add non-contact fields (such as membership, contribution, relationship, etc) in bulk emails?

Tags: templates, tokens, email

I want to add fields from other modules, such as membership,contributions, relationships etc in bulk emails? I don't know php so I hope I can put the field name inside {}.

Is this possible?  If so, how do I know what the full name would be?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "not without extensions". It would be difficult, for instance, to say exactly which of a contact's many contributions you want to pull data from.

That said, other users have created extensions that give you many of the most commonly needed tokens. Check out the [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields), [Contributions Table](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contributions-table-token), and [Eileen's custom tokens](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/tokens), in that order.

Comment: @Marilyn Schiffman - Oops - I screwed up my original post!  My recommendations are now much more helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Find Participants and then send email to contacts, or similarly Find members or Find contributions, then use Smarty variables for the component core and custom fields as I suspect there are no tokens coded yet. If this doesn't yet work it should be fairly easy to add.