# Fuzion tokens for membership start and end date

Tags: civimember, tokens

I want to use Fuzion tokens in an attachment letter (an insurance certificate) and I need to show up start and end date for this certificate.

It's easy for name and everything related to contact or custom fields but I don't find for the start and end dates.

Is it something like `{contact.membership_start_date}` & `{contact.membership_end_date}`?

Will these customs fields work?
Is there a way to find them (documentation, ...)?

**EDIT : 18/06/2019**

I tried the Fuzion tokens found with Jon's help but unfortunately the {membership.*_*} fields didn't work in my document. Others worked well. I thought at first, it didn't work out because the test user used had no contribution date, but actually even with one I can't get the token working.

[image]

[image]

Has anybody already succeeded in using those fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after searching round and round, I finally found a simple extension: [civitoken](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken) which permits to use many tokens and solved my question.

Actually Jon G already showed the way: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/294/6991

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that a contact can have multiple memberships, so you can't use membership tokens unless you display your search results as memberships.

In Advanced Search, do your search again, but change **Display Results As** from *Contacts* to **Memberships**.  If your contacts only have one membership each, this is all you need to do; if they can have multiple memberships, you probably need to filter by date, membership type, or status to get the correct ones.

From the search action selector, you'll now have the option **Print/merge document for membership**.  When you select that, the list of tokens will include membership start and end dates.

UPDATE: I've posted a video here demonstrating what I believe is the answer to the question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5D2aLoW9ovU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Great Jon! I found the fields and they are : {membership.start_date}{membership.end_date}

Comment: apparently it doesn't do what I need :(

Comment: @GuillaumeSorel I'm confused by your update.  You say "it didn't work out because the test user used no no contribution date, but actually event...".  I'm not sure what the connection is between your membership, events, and contributions.  I think there is also a language barrier.  Maybe join https://chat.civicrm.org and ask the question in the ~francophone channel?  They may also be able to assist in translating your question here.

Comment: G I've edited my question to correct my sentence. So I confirm that even with a registered user if I send an Email, normal fields are fusionned but not those you helped me to find. This is really bothering because our client really needs this service.

Comment: I found this topic: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/7156/6991 and apparently as Jon G said I can't get this result. But what if I only have 1 membership? This shouldn't be to confusing, no?

Comment: @GuillaumeSorel I added a video to my question, hopefully it helps.  Also note that "Fuzion tokens" is an extension that provides additional tokens.  This feature is just "tokens", and doesn't require any extensions.

Comment: thanks for your video! and your help